# ¿Qué operaciones se pueden hacer en un arreglo de Numpy pero NO en una lista?

Tags: python, numpy

Hola estoy queriendo averiguar si este codigo es correcto a lo que pregunto?
gracias.

```
m= np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]) # Multiplicacion
print(m.shape) # Salida (3,3)

n= np.array([[2,3,5,6,7], [3,7,8,9,2]])
print(n.shape) # Salida (2,5)
```

Comment: Si se ejecuta sin errores y hace lo que debiera de hacer, diría que si es correcto. Pero sin saber exactamente qué es lo que se supone que haga, ¿cómo poder decir si es correcto o no?

Comment: si te refieres a si la operación `.shape` se puede aplicar a un array numpy pero no a una lista, sí, correcto, las listas no tienen `.shape`

Comment: El titulo dice que estás preguntando por diferencias entre operar un array numpy y una lista. Pero el cuerpo mostrás un código en el que no estás operando listas, solo las usás de intermedio para inicializar arrays numpy. Además, que significa que un código sea "correcto"? Que funcione bien? Que haga lo que esperas? Por que la pregunta del titulo no se puede responder con las palabras correcto o incorrecto, si no con información. Por cierto, el código hace lo que esperaban los desarrolladores de numpy, funciona bien y sin errores.

Comment: Como podrás ver, todos estamos confundidos, ese hecho disminuirá el número de respuestas por que no sabemos lo que querés decir y aumenta enormemente la posibilidad de que las que recibas no estén enfocadas en el problema que nos querés plantear debido a que no queda claro. Recomiendo que [edites](/edit) la pregunta y la reformules.

Answer (score 1):

Vale, si te refieres a comparten y difieren ambos objectos, hay dos opciones:

- usar `dir()` en ambos:

```
dir(list) 
dir(np.ndarray) #ndarray por que es el objecto padre de np.array
```

Esto te dara tanto las propiedades de cada objecto ( _ _ NOMBRE DE LA PROPIEDAD _ _ ) como los metodos de cada uno (los que no tienen doble _ <<o dunder (double underscore) en ingles>>). Esto con el fin de que los puedas comparar uno a uno.

- Revisar la referencia oficinal de ambos (revisar que la version de la referencia empate con la version que tengas instalada):

**Python:**

Sobre la estructura de datos "list":
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists

Sobre los metodos y mas informacion de "list"
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

**Numpy:**

Sobre np.array:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Ahora, si te refieres a que operaciones (matematicas) se pueden hacer en numpy y cuales en las listas, la referencias previas deberian de responder esto. Sin embargo, para sintetizar a muy grosso modo, las listas son una coleccion de datos o de otras estructuras de datos, mientras que los np.array pueden verse como estructuras que emulan una matriz.

Esto significa que no siempre se pueden hacer operaciones matematicas directas en las listas, pues pueden tener valores que no necesariamente permitiran esto (intentar multiplicar una listas de str por otra de str). Sin embargo, existen formas de poderlo hacerlo (ciclos `for`, `zip`, comprensiones, etc). Pero podria entrar en una categoria diferente a operaciones matematicas

Por su lado, si bien lo mismo puede llegar a aplicar para np.array, debido a que se suele usar en contextos numericos, se puede asumir, o en el caso estricto, definir los dtypes como numericos, por lo que operaciones de matrices suelen ser mas directas, por lo que se pueden usar las herramientas existentes de numpy. Me parece que un punto de partida podria ser el modulo de numpy de algebra linear. Igual y aqui podrias probar usando tanto `list` como `np.array` para solventar la duda:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.linalg.html#linear-algebra-numpy-linalg

Saludos.